# Starting An Activity From BroadCast Receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

My app is consisted of many activities and a `BraodcastReceiver`. I want to restart an activity if it is on foreground when my app receives the broadcast Intent.How can I implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT) to launch activity to be brought to the front of its task's history stack if it is already running and if not then start as new one. to make confirm if Activity is running or not use [ActivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html)

```
    @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //start activity
            if(isRunning(context)){

             Intent i = new Intent(context,Your_Activity_Name.class);
             i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
             context.startActivity(i);
            }
           else{
                 // Activity not available in activity stack
            }
        }

  public boolean isRunning(Context ctx) {
        ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) 
                         ctx.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = 
                      activityManager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);

        for (RunningTaskInfo task : tasks) {
            if (ctx.getPackageName().equalsIgnoreCase(
                                     task.baseActivity.getPackageName())) 
                return true;                                  
        }

        return false;
    }
```

and also set [android:noHistory](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist) `AndroidManifest.xml` to store Activity in  activity stack  no longer visible on screen :

```
<activity
       android:noHistory="false"
       android:name=".Your_Activity" />
```

Comment: *"Your_Activity_Name.this"* - that should be `.class` and not `.this`

Comment: No problem - we all make mistakes like that. :)

Comment: Its working but I want to restart my activity only if it is on foreground but with this piece of snippet, I am redirected to that activity even if it is not on foreground..
Is there any check I can make to do this only if my that particular acitvity is on foreground??

Comment: @aneelasafdar : this is my mistake to understand your question then use `ActivityManager` to check if your Activity is in foreground or not before starting it .

Comment: Thankyou so much, it worked exactly what I want just after a small check :)

Answer (score 0):

Make the activity `singleTop` and just send the intent.